# HTML Hidden Field not receiving Model Attribute value in Spring Boot Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hidden-field

I have s Spring Boot Application using Thymeleaf templating engine, that is suppose to submit a form and then proceed to the next page taking an ID from the previous submit function. 
But when I added the value to the hidden field on the next view, it is not accepting it.
I want to know what am doing wrong.

> Controller

```
   @Controller
   public class FormController {
    @Autowired
    UserCategoryServiceImpl userCategoryService;

    @GetMapping("/form3")
    public String getForm3(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("form3", new UserCategory());
        return "form3";
    }

    @PostMapping("/form3")
    public String postAndGetForm4(@ModelAttribute UserCategory userCategory, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult){
        userCategoryService.saveCategory(userCategory);
        model.addAttribute("catID", userCategory.getId());
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "form3";
        }
        return "form4";
    }
}
```

> Views
>
> 1: Form3

```
<form method="post" th:object="${form3}">
    <label>Name</label><input th:field="*{name}" type="text" name="userName">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> 2: Form4

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="*{catID}">
</form>
```

> Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_category")
public class UserCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
//Getter and Setters
```

The first form(Form3) submits successfully but the value of the **catID** fails to display on the hidden field of the next form(Form4)

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, and perhaps you have already solved it but without posting your resolution in Stack Overflow.

The posted code is incomplete, but it looks to me as if in Form4 you should be using a model attribute directly rather than a field of an attribute.

In Form3, `*{name}` is a field of the model attribute `${form3}` so that syntax works. But in Form4, `catID` is a completely independent model attribute and so in your Thymeleaf template you should have used the dollar sign and not the asterisk, as in `th:value="${catID}"`.

BTW, I noticed that you did not use the closing slash for your input tags. That may work but it's bad practice because it is malformed XML.

And finally, for the last form if you want to use the value directly, you need to specify the `input` tag's `name` attribute manually: `<input type="hidden" name="catID" th:value="${catID}"/>`

**Note:** Using `th:field=${catId}` won't work, because `th:field` requires use of `th:object` on the `form` tag.